# Program wont terminate - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to use an `if else` statement for a menu selection in my program.  Whenever I type in the number given to quit the application, the application still runs.  I'm not sure what I should to do to fix this but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Gradebook {

    public static void main(String[] args ){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("(1) Average grades for a new student");
        System.out.println("(2) Quit");
        int selection = input.nextInt();

        if( selection == 1) {
            System.out.println("Grades will be put in accordingly: \n Homework \n Quizzes \n Tests");
            System.out.println("Once all grades have been put in, type -1 to continue");
            String name = input.next();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        }

        int total = 0;
        int counter = 0;


        System.out.println("Please enter numeric homework grade or \"-1\" to quit: ");
        int grade = input.nextInt();

        while( grade != -1) {
            total = total + grade;
            counter = counter + 1;
        grade= input.nextInt();
        }

        if (counter > 0) {
                double average = total / (double)counter;
                System.out.println("The average for Homework is: " + average);
        }
        else
                System.out.println("No grades were entered."); 

        System.out.println("Please enter numeric Quiz grade or \"-1\" to quit: ");

        while( grade != -1) {
            total = total + grade;
            counter = counter + 1;
        grade = input.nextInt();
        }

        if(counter > 0) {
            double average = total / (double)counter;
            System.out.println("The average for Quizzes is: " + average);
        }
        else
                System.out.println("No grades were entered.");

                System.out.println("Please enter numeric Test grade or \"-1\" to quit: ");

            while(grade != -1) {
                total = total + grade;
                counter = counter + 1;
            grade = input.nextInt();
            }

            if(counter > 0) {
                double average = total / (double)counter;
                System.out.println("The average for Tests is: " + average);
            }
            else
                    System.out.println("No grades were entered.");

    }

}
```

Comment: Try `System.exit(0);` to quit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the code that is supposed to exit:

```
    else{
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
    }
```

Printing "Goodbye", however, does not quit the application. Try this:

```
    else{
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        System.exit(0); // causes the application to end right here
    }
```

or:

```
    else{
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        return; // returns from the main function
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to do this: Change the if statement to contain `return`, or change the if statement to contain [`System.exit(0)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)).

With `return`:

```
    if( selection == 1) {
        System.out.println("Grades will be put in accordingly: \n Homework \n Quizzes \n Tests");
        System.out.println("Once all grades have been put in, type -1 to continue");
        String name = input.next();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        return;
    }
```

With `System.exit`:

```
    if( selection == 1) {
        System.out.println("Grades will be put in accordingly: \n Homework \n Quizzes \n Tests");
        System.out.println("Once all grades have been put in, type -1 to continue");
        String name = input.next();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```